# Searching in DataGrid via TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and i want to add search option by using a `TextBox` and search button. The result should be selection of the entire row based on the textbox content.

My code is something like this :

```
public void search()
{
    String searchValue = textBox1.Text;
    int rowIndex = -1;
    foreach (//Row in MydataGrid)
    {
        if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
        {
            rowIndex = row.Index;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, all the relevant links were sl... [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx)...

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just search through the bound items?

Comment: Use collectionViewSource?

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that you are looking in some row that have this this Group Class:

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a column in DataGrid that calls only the Group.Name:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgGroups">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

So, if you want to search in the Datagrid for a specific name, you could use:

```
private Group SearchGroup(string searchName)
{
    foreach (Group g in dtgGroups.Items)
    {
        if (g.Name == searchName) return g;
    }

    return null;
}
```

And it will returns you the group that you searched.

Comment: Hello Butzke , thank you for you quick response , i get an error while executing the search : +  _ex {System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'TestInfo'.
   at WpfApplication1.MainWindow.SearchTestInfo(String searchName) in C:\Users\Danip\Desktop\to delete\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 57} System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

Comment: @DaniPedrossa Could you post your entire code? Its difficult to say something just with the error message.

Comment: i have an excel file in C drive, this .xls is loaded in DataGride1 by class caled ExcelDataCMF1 ExcelDataCMF1 exceldata = new ExcelDataCMF1();
            this.dataGrid1.DataContext = exceldata; the xls file contain (Int ,String type) , after that i have used your code and catch an exception !! any idea please

Comment: @DaniPedrossa how is declared the ExcelDataCMF1 class?

Comment: declared as Public :
   public class ExcelDataCMF1
    {
        public DataView Data
        {
            get
            {
                Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook workbook;
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet;
                Excel.Range range;
                workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Danip\Desktop\Training TPM\CMF1 DOC\TestoDasi.xlsx");
                worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets["Test Sheet"];

Comment: int column = 0;
                int row = 0;

                range = worksheet.UsedRange;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("INDEX");
                dt.Columns.Add("MTX");
                dt.Columns.Add("GP");
                dt.Columns.Add("MTX_GPIB");
                for (row = 2; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (column = 1; column <= range.Columns.Count; column++)

Comment: {
                        dr[column - 1] = (range.Cells[row, column] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    dt.AcceptChanges();
                }
                workbook.Close(true);
                excelApp.Quit();
                return dt.DefaultView;

Comment: @DaniPedrossa you are using `DataTable`? In your question you are asking for a `Datagrid`, as the example that I gave you.

Comment: yes im using a dataTable and i bind the result to my data grid by  ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" sorry Butzkefor not mentioning that in my question

Comment: @DaniPedrossa Its ok! Its that in the first sentence you are telling that I have a DataGrid and not a DataTable. If this is correct, please edit your question.